# Select from dropdown item and return multiple attributes

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make a food trace ability list and I am trying to help speed up the process of completing it.

I have put all my seed stock into a table under an excel tab called stock.

Stock Table
[image]

I've then made a list from that table.

I've then applied data validation list to `column C`

Food traceability page
[image]

I'm basically trying to make it so when I select a seed from the drop down it autocomplete the batch to save me filling it in.

I've tried using the following formula and it is returning "Seed Batch"  (Table Column Name)

Anyone able to help?

Comment: It's not immediately clear what you want. Ir `order = ItemNum`? What do you want to import? The current inventory? Are any items duplicated? It would help if you maybe showed an example of this working for one row. Make sure to show the raw data and the final output

Comment: Can't you just use vlookup?

Answer (score 0):

Would a vlookup work for you in the 'Seed Batch' column?

=VLOOKUP(C3,*StockTable*[[ItemNum]:[Batch]],3,0)